# RSA cryptosystem test question - help please!

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Suppose that the 26 symbol alphabet $A,...,Z$ is used for all plaintext and ciphertext messages in an RSA cryptosystem. Suppose also that plaintext message units are length $2$ and ciphertext units are length $3$.

A user has a public key $(943,3)$

i) Encrypt for transmission to A the message

MATHEMATICAL

---

Okay, so $(943,3)$ = (n, e). $k=2, l=3$.

$943=23*41$

MATHEMATICAL = $12, 0, 19, 7, 4, 12, 0, 19, 8, 2, 0, 11$

What are the next steps? How do I finish this? The example is my notes is fairly complicated and uses Maple for one of the calculations which is confusing me as we have to do this in a class test? .. Without access to any computer programs...

If someone could explain this to me, that would be great! :)

Comment: 1st, $943\ne21\times41$. Second, one thing you have to do, *before* you can do any encrypting, is turn the message into a number (or string of numbers). You have to look at that example in the notes to see how they do that. This is before Maple or anything complicated gets done.

Comment: I meant 23*41! I blame the panic :P I have MATHEMATICAL as 12,0,19,7,4,12,0,19,8,2,0,11

Comment: Sorry, I don't do fast help.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think person is studying for some exam. I think they should have done this earlier and not two hours before according to their previous post on the same topic :).

Comment: Okay? I was just asking for help here as I only have one example in my notes which is quite complicated. I'm sorry if the word "fast" offended you. I was just hoping that I might receive an answer before the class test. If not it's not the end of the world.

Comment: @gekkostate This is true! But as I said, not the end of the world. It's worth very little of my final grade. I have the majority of stuff covered anyway, this is the only thing left. Thanks for your reply on my other post :) Even if I get a late reply it will still prove useful in my final exam.

Comment: Panda, when you are asking people who owe you nothing for free help, you don't tell them to hurry up.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If it was taken that way I apologise, but that was not how I meant it to come across.

Comment: @gekkostate Haha thanks for the edit! :)

Comment: I may be wrong, but the part "plaintext message units are length 2 and ciphertext units are length 3" seems to ask you to pack every two integers from the plaintext stream into a single RSA input $m \mapsto c = m^e \pmod{n}$. The RSA output $c$ is then break into 3 integers in $0, \ldots, 25$ and send to output in corresponding output alphabets.

Comment: @achillehui, since the modulus is 943, all ciphertexts will have 3 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSA encryption works as follows, you have a modulus $n$ (in this case $943$) and an encryption exponent $e$ (in this case $3$). To encrypt a plaintext message $m$ you compute $c=m^e\bmod{n}$. So, if $m=12$, we get $12^3\equiv 785 \bmod{943}$.